# Trigger Insert ONLY if column value contains XXXX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Let's say we have a table where there are many Unique codes combined. For example: Bill No:

- XOUT12345
- SOUT12345
  etc.

I wanted to create a trigger that ensures only the ones with value 'XOUT%' get used in the trigger and inserted into another table. This specifically seemed to work (I think) however, then when I create a document where format B is used, I get an error saving the document.

**The tables are as follows:**

1. 1 table called ICSTOCKBILL where all deliveries coming in and out are
   saved into that one table using the formats as described above.
2. One column = FBillNo where the bill numbers are registered to.
3. One column = FStatus, where the approval status is updated to 1 if so.

1 Table called 3026 where the stock bill numbers from ICSTOCKBILL (FBillNo) should automatically be transferred to.

**My code is as follows**:

```
create Trigger DVLP_T_InsertBillNoItemSALESDEL2 On ICStockBill
for UpDate
as
If UpDate(FStatus)  
Begin
    If not exists (Select 1 
                  From inserted a 
                  Inner Join t_Item b on b.FItemClassID=3026 AND b.FNumber=a.FBillNo where FBillNo like 'XOUT%')
    Begin
        INSERT INTO t_Item (FItemClassID,FParentID,FLevel,FName,FNumber,FShortNumber,FFullNumber,FFullName,FDetail,FDeleted) 
        Select 3026,0,1,FBillNo,FBillNo,FBillNo,FBillNo,FBillNo,1,0
        From inserted where FBillNo like 'XOUT%'

    End
End
```

> So the end goal is: All documents that are approved (FStatus =
>   updated) must run through the trigger. But ONLY those with XOUT format
>   should be inserted into Table 3026.

So far, after I apply this trigger, it works. I create a new sales delivery, it's not in the new table yet. I approve it, and it's there.

However, other documents that do not have said format, get the error:

> UPDATE ICSTOCKBILL SET FORDERAFFIRM=0 WHERE FBILLNO=SEOUT1234 violiation of UNIQUE KEY contraint 'item2;.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Dale, thank you for your  tips. For some reason, since I've created this trigger, other documents that also submit to the same table get errors in submitting. These submissions will also update columnA and therefore the trigger will also run. But they don't have any values matching those defined in the trigger. I assumed this was the issue, i could be wrong (i'm a noob). I was hoping there would be a way to say if (x = x) instead of if update(columnA)..

Comment: Thank you Dale, I updated it with as much info as I could think of. So as described, the trigger works perfectly, it's just that when the trigger is there, the other documents in that same table get the error. When I remove the trigger, the error doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: So which table has column `item2`?

Comment: ICStockkBill has this column sorry, I'm going to try your method now! thanks! I'll report back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the entire trigger by using proper set based logic - instead of procedural logic.

The following should accomplish what you are asking for.

```
create trigger DVLP_T_InsertBillNoItemSALESDEL2 on ICStockBill
for update
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    -- Always use meaningful aliases - using a, b, c is asking for trouble
    insert into t_Item (FItemClassID, FParentID, FLevel, FName, FNumber, FShortNumber, FFullNumber, FFullName, FDetail, FDeleted) 
    select 3026, 0, 1, FBillNo, FBillNo, FBillNo, FBillNo, FBillNo, 1, 0
    from Inserted I
    where FBillNo like 'XOUT%'
    and FStatus = 1
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from t_Item IT
        where IT.FItemClassID = 3026
        and IT.FNumber = I.FBillNo
    );
end
```

If you are still getting the error originally reported then I very much doubt it has anything to do with the trigger. Its reporting that a unique constraint on the main table has been violated, and the trigger doesn't touch that table. I suspect your test data might not be unique enough.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Dale, learned a lot from this. Tidied up my code and it works well now. Still unsure what caused the error but it seems to be gone. Appreciate it!